# How to show new products from right column to center column in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop

As per the given articles on internet i have made my home page 1 page column means no left and right columns are here. now its working fine. I want to have new product in center column instead of right column.
How to do this in prestashop?

Answer (score 0):

Go to modules tab, then positions subtab, you can select your module and put it in "center column" hook.